# How to Create Testimonial Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I have to create a **slider plugin for testimonial** to show in a webpage, the testimonial item should be visible **one at a time**, I have created basic blocks in HTML and jquery.I used setTimeOut function to hide and show testimonial item inside **each** function, but it not works properly. I am pasting my code here

** HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6 testimonial-wrapper">

                    <div class="testimonial-item" style="display: block; opacity: 0.872447;">
                        <h3>
                            Testimonials</h3>
                        <hr style="height: 4px; border: none; color: #333; background-color: #7BC83A;; width: 70px;
                            margin-left: 0;">
                        <h4>
                          Shaf/ Seo</h4>
                        <blockquote>
                            <p>Hi                      
                            </p>
                        </blockquote>
                     </div>

                    <div class="testimonial-item" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">
                        <h3>
                            Testimonials</h3>
                        <hr style="height: 4px; border: none; color: #333; background-color: #7BC83A;; width: 70px;
                            margin-left: 0;">
                        <h4>
                          Shaje/ As</h4>
                        <blockquote>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum Simply Dummy text Lorem Ipsum Simply Dummy text Lorem Ipsum Simply Dummy text Lorem Ipsum Simply Dummy text                       
                            </p>
                        </blockquote>
                     </div>

           </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var wrapper = $(".testimonial-wrapper");
    var testimonialItem = $(".testimonial-wrapper .testimonial-item");
    var timeOut = 10000;
    var lengthOfItem = testimonialItem.length;
    var counter = 0;

    startIteration();



    function startIteration() {
        testimonialItem.each(function () {
            var current = $(this);
            setInterval(startTestimonialSlider(current), timeOut);
            counter++;
            debugger;
            if (counter == lengthOfItem) {
                counter = 0;
                debugger;
                startIteration();
            }

        });

    }

    function startTestimonialSlider(itemToDisplay) {
        itemToDisplay.prev().fadeOut();
        itemToDisplay.fadeIn();
    }

});
```

This is not working properly.

Please look at the fiddled code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/qttpop3z/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is what you wanted to do right ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

var testimonialItem = $(".testimonial-wrapper .testimonial-item");
var lengthOfItem = testimonialItem.length;
var counter = 0;
    
testimonialItem.hide();
setTimeout(function(){
startIteration(counter);
}, 1000);


function startIteration(counter) {
testimonialItem.eq(counter).fadeIn('slow', function() {
if(counter<=lengthOfItem){ 
setTimeout(function(){ 
testimonialItem.fadeOut('slow',function(){
if (counter == lengthOfItem) {
counter = 0;  
}else{
counter++;}
setTimeout(function(){ startIteration(counter);}, 500);    
});}, 2000);
}
});
}

    


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 testimonial-wrapper">
    <div class="testimonial-item" style="display: block; opacity: 0.872447;">
         <h3>Testimonials</h3>

        <hr style="height: 4px; border: none; color: #333; background-color: #7BC83A;; width: 70px;margin-left: 0;">
         <h4>Shaf/ Seo</h4>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Hi</p>
        </blockquote>
 </div>
    <div class="testimonial-item" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">
         <h3>
                                Testimonials</h3>

        <hr style="height: 4px; border: none; color: #333; background-color: #7BC83A;; width: 70px;
                                margin-left: 0;">
         <h4>
                              Shaje/ As</h4>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Simply Dummy text Lorem Ipsum Simply Dummy text Lorem Ipsum Simply Dummy text Lorem Ipsum Simply Dummy text</p>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```